# R code 'runs' fine in Rstudio but fails devtools::load_all() check

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

This line of code works fine when I 'run' it in Rstudio

```
dt.SSPGDP[, GDP.lag1 :=shift(value), by=c("ISO_code","scenario")]
```

But when I run devtools::load_all(), I get the following error message

```
Error in `:=`(GDP.lag1, shift(value)) (from dataManagement.alcohol.R#37) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

I checked that dt.SSPGDP is in fact a data table.

Any tips on how to fix?

Comment: Is this in an example? Within in a function in a package? Something else?

Comment: I guess this in a package and you didn't `import` data.table in your DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files.

Comment: This is a line of code in an R script. I'm trying to figure out how to convert this, and several other scripts, into a package. I have purchased @Hadley Wickham's R Packages book and have been using it to guide my development. The key section on R code workflow, step 2 (Press Ctrl/Cmd-Shift-L) is where the error arises.

Comment: My NAMESPACE file only holds `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")`. The DESCRIPTION file has `Imports: data.table, ggplot2, roxygen2, plotrix, plyr, dplyr, openxlsx, splitstackshape, stringi, tidyr, gdxrrw' so it seems like I am in fact importing data.table.

Comment: You need to add `import(data.table)` to your NAMESPACE file.

Comment: Or since you use roxygen2, you can add `#' @import data.table` in your source code. Btw. , it shouldn't be necessary to import roxygen2.